# Why SQL UPDATE actually performs a DELETE instead?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have the following code and when it executes on the record being `UPDATED`, the record actually ends up being `DELETED` from the database table. This is an Oracle Database. Very odd. So far, I have been unable to pull any logging information from the database server that might explain what is happening on a lower level. `The System.out.println` statements that I included show the  output that I am expecting at the moment they execute, yet, when I search for the record both via the java application itself, and then later via the SQL Developer tool - looking at the table itself, the actual data is gone. This is the java code that I have. Any thoughts, ideas, or answers as to how and why an update would perform a delete, instead of just an update is appreciated, thanks. Please let me know if there is anything else you might need that I have not properly provided, thanks.

```
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
.
.
.
     if(PBupdate.equals("updaterecords")) {
        try {

    ArrayList resultsArray = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("searchresults");
    int pos = 0;
    String ID = "";
    System.out.println("updatestaff : pos = " + pos + " resultsArray.size() = " + resultsArray.size());
    while (pos < resultsArray.size()) {

       System.out.println("updatestaff : pos = " + pos);
       System.out.println("updatestaff : resultsArray.get(pos + 1) = " + resultsArray.get(pos + 1));

       ID = "" + resultsArray.get(pos + 0) + "";
       Last_Name = "" + resultsArray.get(pos + 1) + "";
       First_Name = "" + resultsArray.get(pos + 2) + "";
       Middle = "" + resultsArray.get(pos + 3) + "";
       Phone  = "" + resultsArray.get(pos + 4) + "";
       Dept_Code = "" + resultsArray.get(pos + 5) + "";
       Email  = "" + resultsArray.get(pos + 6) + "";  
       Title = "" + resultsArray.get(pos + 7) + "";
       Fax_Code = "" + resultsArray.get(pos + 8) + "";
       Loc_Code = "" + resultsArray.get(pos + 9) + "";

       System.out.println("updatestaff : ID = " + ID);
       System.out.println("updatestaff : Last_Name = " + Last_Name);
       System.out.println("updatestaff : First_Name = " + First_Name);
       System.out.println("updatestaff : Middle = " + Middle);                 
       System.out.println("updatestaff : Phone = " + Phone);
       System.out.println("updatestaff : Dept_Code = " + Dept_Code);
       System.out.println("updatestaff : Email = " + Email);
       System.out.println("updatestaff : Title = " + Title);
       System.out.println("updatestaff : Fax_Code = " + Fax_Code);                 
       System.out.println("updatestaff : Loc_Code = " + Loc_Code);

       stmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE STAFFDIR SET Last_Name = ?, First_Name = ?, Middle = ?, Phone = ?, Dept_Code = ?, Email = ?, Title = ?, Fax_Code = ?, Loc_Code = ?  WHERE ID = ?");

               stmt.setString(1, Last_Name);
               stmt.setString(2, First_Name);                   
               stmt.setString(3, Middle);
               stmt.setString(4, Phone);
           Integer DC = Integer.valueOf(Dept_Code);

           System.out.println("updatestaff: Dept_Code = " + Dept_Code);

               stmt.setInt(5, DC);
               stmt.setString(6, Email);
               stmt.setString(7, Title);
               if ((Fax_Code == null) || (Fax_Code.equals("")) || (Fax_Code.equals("null"))) {
                    Fax_Code = "999";
               }

           System.out.println("updatestaff: Fax_Code = " + Fax_Code);  

           Integer FC = Integer.valueOf(Fax_Code);
               stmt.setInt(8, FC);
           Integer LC = Integer.valueOf(Loc_Code);

           System.out.println("updatestaff: Loc_Code = " + Loc_Code);

               stmt.setInt(9, LC);                 
       stmt.setString(10, ID);
               int rc = stmt.executeUpdate(); 

               System.out.println("update : rc = " + rc);

               SQLWarning warning = conn.getWarnings();
               while (warning != null)
               {
                 System.out.println(warning.getMessage());
                 warning = warning.getNextWarning();
               }

               pos = pos + 14;     
       }       
       response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("/phonebk/updatestaff.jsp"));  
    } // End of try
```

Comment: Just a quick idea. By any chance is there some trigger on the table you are updating?

Comment: please use try ..catch block. throw an exception

Comment: any chance that you are updating the ID and then expecting to get data back using the old ID. Not knowing the restrictions on your table, it would be difficult to guess what's happening.

Comment: your ID is without value.

Comment: Do you have the generated SQL statement?  Take that statement and run it directly through a SQL command line tool like TOAD.  If the same thing happens, you know the issue is at the database level.

Comment: Hmm, I actually do not know. I will go back into SQL Developer tool and look at how the DB is defined as well as ask our DBA about that. I'm just the app developer so I cannot say for sure if something that I am doing is triggering something else on the DB defined side that is altering my original intent. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I was responding to the trigger comment just now.

Comment: What makes you think the row is being deleted?  How are you verifying this?

Comment: Kumaresan, I am using Rational Developer tool to make my mods to this (previously written by me) application (I neglected to allow those that do updates to update a fax number for someone). My attempt at allow this is somehow causing records to disappear. I'll be damned if I know what I did to cause that. ID has a value. And SystemErr.log has no exception in it. Here is the output that was displayed in the SystemOut.log file...

Comment: [6/20/17 15:24:06:711 EDT] 0000002c SystemOut     O updatestaff : pos = 0 resultsArray.size() = 14
 [6/20/17 15:24:06:711 EDT] 0000002c SystemOut     O updatestaff : pos = 0
 [6/20/17 15:24:06:711 EDT] 0000002c SystemOut     O updatestaff : resultsArray.get(pos + 1) = Carlos
 [6/20/17 15:24:06:711 EDT] 0000002c SystemOut     O updatestaff : ID = 468
 [6/20/17 15:24:06:711 EDT] 0000002c SystemOut     O updatestaff : Last_Name = Carlos
 [6/20/17 15:24:06:711 EDT] 0000002c SystemOut     O updatestaff : First_Name = Sierra

Comment: [6/20/17 15:24:06:711 EDT] 0000002c SystemOut     O updatestaff : Middle = null
 [6/20/17 15:24:06:711 EDT] 0000002c SystemOut     O updatestaff : Phone = (999) 999-9999 :-) :-)
 [6/20/17 15:24:06:711 EDT] 0000002c SystemOut     O updatestaff : Dept_Code = 174
 [6/20/17 15:24:06:711 EDT] 0000002c SystemOut     O updatestaff : Email = Carlos.Sierra@ xxx.yyy :-)
 [6/20/17 15:24:06:711 EDT] 0000002c SystemOut     O updatestaff : Title = Special Projects & Community Activities Outreach
 [6/20/17 15:24:06:711 EDT] 0000002c SystemOut     O updatestaff : Fax_Code = 999

Comment: [6/20/17 15:24:06:721 EDT] 0000002c SystemOut     O updatestaff: Dept_Code = 174
 [6/20/17 15:24:06:721 EDT] 0000002c SystemOut     O updatestaff: Fax_Code = 999
 [6/20/17 15:24:06:721 EDT] 0000002c SystemOut     O updatestaff: Loc_Code = 37
        [6/20/17 15:24:06:721 EDT] 0000002c SystemOut     O update : rc = 1

Comment: "... somehow causing records to disappear ..." - what makes you think so?

Comment: As you have written this application before and it was working, you have source code of original version stored somewhere in git or at least in some folder before you started modifications. Then take this code and diff what you have changed. It might give you some hints.

Comment: Dawood, because the record can not be found in the DB after the update completes.

Comment: Is there an ORM entity associated with that table? Its possible you have code somewhere else that is causing the entity associated with that row to be orphaned and then deleted.

Comment: Is ID  really string? `stmt.setString(10, ID)` I don't see why it should cause delete of record. Just guessing.

Comment: Marek, I opened the DB using SQL Developer and I find no Triggers defined. Also, its the same code with system.out.println added for debugging purposes. I used this code in the past. What changed was other code that brings an updater here. This always had FAX_CODE with value of 999 because after an office move, everyones FAX_CODE  was set that way. They didn't care about fax numbers then, but that was then. But regardless of a users info being updated, it doesn't seem to matter if the FAX_CODE is 999 or some other number actually associated with a fax code. The record ends up being deleted.

Comment: Marek, to continiue...for a select few in the beginning I simply edited the directory table for the updaters, but of course, that is a little silly. Not only should they have the ability to add and delete a fax number from the fax table, they should have the ability to update a persons information (fax number included) and that is the functionality that I was trying to give them to take myself out of the loop of editing certain data for them, sometimes.

Comment: And they have the ability to add/delete fax numbers from the fax table thru the web interface I created for them. Same for locations. Same for department names. This is a relatively simple 4 table relational database. I am not editing the code end users use to search the phone directory, but rather editing the application others use to maintain the data in said phone directory. Hope all of this helps to explain.

Comment: "...  the record can not be found in the DB ..." - by what mechanism are you looking for it?  I don't believe that it's being deleted - any more than I believe that my car ceases to exist when I drive it out of my driveway.  You're simply looking for it wrong.  So how are you looking for it?

Comment: "What changed was other code that brings an updater here." Then you should be probably focusing on that other code. Maybe take a step back and get back to the version where it worked and start applying your changes. There is nothing obvious in the piece of code you provided to us.

Comment: Maybe try to get more debug information by calling getParameterMetaData() before executeUpdate(). And print out its result.

Comment: In order to find those disappearing records, I would try to search by ID, where ID is null or where it equals any other parameter from "deleted" records. It is more likely, that these records got somehow mixed up rather than deleted. Just simple count of the records in the table before and after update could be hint where they go, if you are willing to lose another record. But it seems, that you prepared one yourself.

Comment: @user3511659: do **NOT** post code, sample data or additional information in comments. [edit] your question instead

Comment: Hi Marek, I'm not exactly sure what this is but ParameterMetaData = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleParameterMetaData@5ced5ced

Comment: Hi Marek, sorry (I need to stop hitting enter so fast :-))   ParameterMetaData abc = stmt.getParameterMetaData();
System.out.println("update : ParameterMetaData = " + abc);
                int rc = stmt.executeUpdate();    I hope I did this the way you intended me too.

Comment: Mike, I will try running that statement from within SQL Developer and let you know. Thank you to all who responded so quickly to my posting yesterday. Didn't expect that so quickly.

Comment: Mike, the record got updated. So the problem sits with the changes to my application changes. I will have to dig deeper.

Comment: Yes, you did it right, maybe it will need to dig deeper into that object. See its [methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ParameterMetaData.html). Anyway I am not sure if it will give you any useful information. I thought, that it will be possible to have look at the data before running query,  but it is not. It only gets structure of the query. Have you tried to search column ID for possible data from other columns? If there isn't some kind of column mixup. And how about number of rows, does it change after edit?